# Adding one canvas to another

Tags: android

How can I use two canvas in my application so that I am able to rotate two bitmap images with different rotation speed

Comment: Why don't you use `RotateAnimation`?

Comment: Hi Reno, I tried with Rotation animation, its rotating image with entire background image. how can I rotate single image without rotating background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use the same canvas?

```
c.save();
c.rotate(rotationAngleForBitmap1);
c.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);
c.restore();
c.rotate(rotationAngleForBitmap2);
c.drawBitmap(bitmap2, matrix, paint)
c.restore();
```

Comment: Hi I want to use two canvas in single app, so that i can rotate two images at different rotation speed.